# Where does API fit in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

From my understanding the view is the html/javascript/page layout, the controller filters and routes commands to views and interacts with models. Models is pretty much database logic. App logic seems to be in a cross between controller and model.

Where does API fit in? Lets say my website interacts with the the api but skips the json part. Would this all be in model? How do I decide what logic shouldnt be in the model and in the controller?

Comment: What does `Lets say my website interacts with the the api but skips the json` mean?

Comment: @SLaks: Instead of serializing output to json which then the api client deserializes again to use (like traditionally api would) I just skip that and use the objects directly

Comment: I'm a bit confused whether you're talking about providing an API or consuming an API.

Comment: @Corbin: Most like providing one. Where do I put it if I am using MVC? But the way I want to write this website is it only uses functions provided by the api so its kind of like a client too

Comment: @AntarrByrd: My question is about if api is part of the model or controller and i am talking about before serialization.

Comment: It should likely be mostly in the controller.  After all, exposing an API is basically the same as a normal request, just the rendering is different.  There's a million different factors that can affect this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works more or less the same. The difference is that you're making AJAX requests to the controller (API) instead of full page requests to the controller (non-API). The returned results (JSON/XML) from the API controller action is the equivalent of your model.

Comment: Ok so it sounds like all (backend and api) logic goes into the model and the view is just client side stuff while the controller is the interaction logic between the two? +1

Comment: That's very open a question as different people do it different ways. There are various patterns. MVC 4 comes with Web API. I had assumed this is what your question was about. NOTE - business logic does not belong in MVC. It belongs in a business layer. MVC is not a replacement for an N-tier architecture. It compliments it by added structure to the interface.

Comment: I use MVC as so: View - display the information from the model, no logic. Model - DTO, no logic. Controller - manage communication between UI and business layers, UI logic and transformations from BO to models happens here.

Comment: DTO: Data Transfer Object. Basically a simple container for the data. A typical example of a DTO is a data contract used in WCF. The object is used simply to transfer the data from one place to another. With a data contract, it goes from server to client and vice versa. With the model (the way I use it), it goes from controller to view and vice versa.